# Is this integer partition studied?

Tags: reference-request, integer-partitions

First, this is my firt post here; I'm not a rigorously trained mathematician so apologies for the abuse of language, or if the problem is too trivial :)

In a finite-system problem in statistical physics, we ended up with an equivalent problem of integer partition:

Given $k, m, n \in \mathbf{N}\cup \left\{0\right\}$ and $k\le m\times n$, find the number of solutions of the following equation
\begin{equation}
k = \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i,
\end{equation}
where $x_i \in \mathbf{N}\cup \left\{0\right\}$, and is restricted by
\begin{equation}
n \ge x_1 \ge x_2 \ldots x_{m-1} \ge x_m \ge 0. 
\end{equation}

The solution of such a problem turned out to be the core part of our calculations. We have found a recursive relation of the desired number of solutions, and it will be nice if we can cite / refer to related references, if they exist, when writing up our manuscript.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You may want to consider adding the (reference-request) tag.

Comment: @WillR Done. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partitions_in_a_rectangle_and_Gaussian_binomial_coefficients) article, under "Partitions in a rectangle and Gaussian binomial coefficients"

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks! How did I miss this subsection when checkimg up WIKI!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find any information about such problems in follow source (see chapter $3$):

*George E. Andrews, The Theory of Partitions, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company.*